# Function that compares two objects and assigns old object prop value to new object prop value if the new value is empty or null?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to ensure that any existing, non-null or empty values are not overwritten with empty or null values from an API call.

For example, assume that,

`originalReference['data']['articleTitle'] = 'Something or other';`

and

`reference['data']['articleTitle'] = '';`,

where `reference` is the object that came back from the API and `originalReference` is the object that existed before the API call (was loaded from MySQL database).

I want to ensure that this function cycles through these complex objects (both should always be of the same length and have the same property names), and reassigns the old value to the new object.

So, in the use case above, after the function is done, the `articleTitle` in the object `reference` will be:

`reference['data']['articleTitle'] = 'Something or other';`

Here is what I have so far:

```
if (referenceLength == originalReferenceLength) {
    try {
        for (var prop in reference) {
            // First check for undefined or null
            if (reference[prop] != undefined) {
                if (reference[prop] != null) {
                    if (typeof reference[prop] == 'string' && reference[prop].trim() == '') {
                        // Assign original value to new object if new value is empty string
                        reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                    }

                    // Check if current prop in both objects is an object
                    if (typeof reference[prop] == 'object' && typeof originalReference[prop] == 'object') {
                        for (var property in reference[prop]) {
                            // Check for undefined or null value in original
                            if (originalReference[prop][property] != undefined) {
                                if (originalReference[prop][property] != null) {
                                    if (reference[prop][property] == null || reference[prop][property] == '') {
                                        // Assign old non-null value to new object if new value is empty or null
                                        reference[prop][property] = originalReference[prop][property];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (Array.isArray(reference[prop]) && typeof Array.isArray(originalReference[prop])) {
                        // Recurse if both are arrays
                        reference[prop].forEach((item, index) => vm.evaluateEmptyValues(item, originalReference[prop][index]));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (originalReference[prop] != undefined) {
                        if (originalReference[prop] != null) {
                            // Assign original value to new object
                            reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (originalReference[prop] != undefined) {
                    if (originalReference[prop] != null) {
                        // Assign original value to new object
                        reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: And ... what doesn't work with that?

Comment: Note: a `!=` comparison to `undefined` is also a `!=` comparison to `null`; in other words, if `!= undefined` is `true`, it's also definitely true that `!= null` is also.

Comment: The reason I added both is that I've realized that there are quirks with assigning `undefined` to a property, but not a `null` value.

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm wondering if anyone can catch if there's something wrong with the function. I have a feeling I am missing specific use cases (but my testing seems to be passing with A/B comparisons). I posted here to see if anyone sees any errors that may stand out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing 2 nested data-structures,target+source,what are appropriate merge-strategies for missing target values compared to their source counterpart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286105/comparing-2-nested-data-structures-targetsource-what-are-appropriate-merge-stra)

Answer (score -1):

Don't think there's anything wrong with it but it could be a lot [DRYer][1] and more reusable.

Specially the iteration of a prop that is an object itself just screams recursion, so here's possible refactoring:

```js
function mergeNewReference(origRef, newRef){
  if(!newRef){
    console.log('newRef is empty, not sure what should happen')
  }else{
    for(prop in newRef){
      var newVal = newRef[prop];
      if(!isNullOrUndefined(newVal)){
        var origVal = origRef[prop];
        if(typeof newVal == typeof origVal && typeof newVal === 'object'){
          mergeNewReference(origVal, newVal)
        }else if(isNullOrUndefined(origVal) || isEmptyString(origVal)){
          origRef[prop] = newVal;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return origRef;
    
}

//These helper methods could be better encapsulated inside the merge method. 
//I'll leave them here for better readability
function isNullOrUndefined(val){
  return val === null || val === undefined;
}
function isEmptyString(str){
  return typeof str == 'string' && str.trim() == ''
}

//----------- TEST ----------
var a = {a: null, b: {ba: 1, bb: {bba: '', bbb: null, bbx: 1, bbd: [9,null,9,9]}}};
var b = {a: 2, b: {ba: 2, bb: {bba: 'Not null', bbb: 2, bbc: 2, bbd: [1,2,3,4,5]}}};

var c = mergeNewReference(a,b);
console.log(c);
```

NOTICE: this will return a different result from you algorithm if you have nested objects with more than one level as it does a deep merge.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself