# How to best pass and merge sub type specific parameters to super at construction time?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, merge, super

I have a main class named `Rule` with a `param` attribute and several subclasses as example:

```js
    class Rule {
      param = {}
      constructor (param) {
        // here I want to add the logic to fuse this.param from child component (all are different) and param provided to the constructor
      }
    }

    class SubRule1 extends Rule {
      param = {
        subparam: {
          values: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
          value: 'A'
        }
      }
      constructor (param) {
        super(param)
      }
    }
    
    class SubRule2 extends Rule {
      param = {
        subparam: {
          values: [1, 2],
          value: 1
        }
      }
      constructor (param) {
        super(param)
      }
    }

    let myrule = new SubRule1({ subparam: 'B' })
    >> expected Object { subparam: { values: ['A', 'B', 'C'], value: 'B' }}
    let myrule2 = new SubRule2({ subparam: 2 })
    >> expected Object { subparam: { values: [1, 2], value: 2 }}
```

When instantiate a new object, I would like to fuse `this.param` and the `param` parameter given to the `constructor` for all the subclasses. I wanted to add the logic in the `Rule` class, however, when accessing `this.param` in the `Rule.constructor` class I do not access the child `this.param` attribute but the one defined in `Rule`.
What would be the right design to properly initiate `this.param` in all subclasses ?

Comment: you can find you're answer here: [https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md][1]

Comment: Why do you even need params inside Subrule?, you can just use the Rule param's and when you are calling super(param), you can pass and edit any other param you want super({..param, subparam1: 'test'})

Comment: I updated the example to be clearer

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? Inheritance, especially in this manner, is almost always evil. What’s the high level goal? Good OOP design injects behaviours into classes instead of relying on behaviour provided by parent classes

Comment: Weird way to ask a question. Anyhow, I have parameters defined in sub classes and the settings can be (or not) provided in the constructor.

Comment: The latest changes which did target all `param` data structures do open an entirely new topic which is described best with ... _**"How to deeply merge two structurally similar objects without loosing data by partial overwrites?"**_ The original question about the best class/constructor/super design gets marginalized in comparison to this silent topic shift.

Comment: @user1595929 ... in addition both new examples in terms of each of the expected results are broken/wrong ... in order to meet the expectations the example codes need to be ... `new SubRule1({ subparam: { value: 'B' } })` instead of `new SubRule1({ subparam: 'B' })` and `new SubRule2({ subparam: { value: 2 } })` instead of `new SubRule2({ subparam: 2 })`

Comment: @user1595929 ... The OP might have a look into one answer of following question ... [_"Comparing 2 nested data-structures,target+source,what are appropriate merge-strategies for missing target values compared to their source counterpart?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286105/comparing-2-nested-data-structures-targetsource-what-are-appropriate-merge-stra/72289681#72289681) ... in order to get some inspiration about deep merging approaches.

Comment: @user1595929 why do subclasses contain those static parameters? Why not have those static parameters defined somewhere else as plain data structures and then you only need your Rule class, no subclasses needed

Comment: Don't use class fields for this. Use arguments that you pass to the `super()` constructor.

Comment: @user1595929 ... From all the provided suggestions / solutions are there any questions left?

Comment: @user1595929 ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

From my above comments ...

> *"The latest changes which did target all `param` data structures do open an entirely new topic which is described best with ... **"How to deeply merge two structurally similar objects without loosing data by partial overwrites?"** The original question about the best `class` / `constructor` / `super` design gets marginalized in comparison to this silent topic shift."*

> *"@user1595929 ... The OP might have a look into one answer of following question ... ["Comparing 2 nested data-structures,target+source,what are appropriate merge-strategies for missing target values compared to their source counterpart?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286105/comparing-2-nested-data-structures-targetsource-what-are-appropriate-merge-stra/72289681#72289681) ... in order to get some inspiration about deep merging approaches."*

> *"@user1595929 ... in addition both new examples in terms of each of the expected results are broken/wrong ... in order to meet the expectations the example codes need to be ... `new SubRule1({ subparam: { value: 'B' } })` instead of `new SubRule1({ subparam: 'B' })` and `new SubRule2({ subparam: { value: 2 } })` instead of `new SubRule2({ subparam: 2 })`"*

**(1)** First things first ... regarding the code comment of the OP's `Rule` constructor ...

> *`// here I want to add the logic to fuse this.param from child component (all are different) and param provided to the constructor`*

... a parent- or super-class has to be oblivious (thus it does not make any assumptions) about child / sub-class properties and operations.

**(2)** In addition, regarding just the handling of each of the Sub/Rules `param` member handling, no inheritance, hence no `Rule`-`SubRule` (parent-child) relationship is even needed. This is due to how at construction time the initialization of each instance's `this.param` gets handled.

Even though as with the OP's example code both (sub-)types `SubRule1` and  `SubRule2` each extend the (super-)type `Rule` the `this.param` initialization is covered/shadowed entirely by each of the types itself. Whatever value `this.param` was, at the end of a super call (chain), at the latest with any sub-type constructor this value gets entirely reassigned/overwritten (like demonstrated with the OP's `params` defaults of `SubRule1` and  `SubRule2`). Thus, if it was not for any other prototypal functionality which hasn't been shown yet, any `Rule` related inheritance is totally unnecessary.

**(3)** Moreover, the OP with one of the more recent edits introduced a far more complex merge behavior for `param` objects than one could have easily achieved with non nested objects and just e.g. ...

```
Object.assign(this.param, param);
```

Instead the expected merger of ...

```
{
  subparam: {
    values: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    value: 'A',
  }
}
```

... and of ...

```
{
  subparam: {
    value: 'B',
  }
}
```

... is ...

```
{
  subparam: {
    values: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    value: 'B',
  }
}
```

... which asks for a custom merge implementation.

**Summary** The OP's main task is rather implementing a suitable custom merge strategy than making use of sub-class/type based inheritance since there most probably might not even be a valid reason for the latter.

The next provided example code proves the above said (though it keeps the inheritance feature, in order to stay with the OP's main code structure).

```js
class Rule {
  param = {};

  constructor (options = {}) {
    // - a simple `Object.assign` is suitable due
    //   to `this.param` being an empty object.
    Object.assign(this.param, options);
  }
}

class SubRule1 extends Rule {
  param = {
    subparam: {
      values: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
      value: 'A',
    },
  };
  constructor (options = {}) {
    super(/*no `options` passing needed due to own `param`*/);
    mergeDataStructures(this.param, options);
  }
}
class SubRule2 extends Rule {
  param = {
    subparam: {
      values: [1, 2],
      value: 1,
    },
  };
  constructor (options = {}) {
    super(/*no `options` passing needed due to own `param`*/);
    mergeDataStructures(this.param, options);
  }
}
const myRule1 = new SubRule1({ subparam: { value: 'B' } });
const myRule2 = new SubRule2({ subparam: { value: 2 } });

console.log({
  myRule1, // { subparam: { values: ['A', 'B', 'C'], value: 'B' }}
  myRule2, // { subparam: { values: [1, 2], value: 2 }}
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// - a pushing/patching approach of assigning/overwriting
//   target-values of deeply nested data-structures.
function mergeDataStructures(target, source) {

  const targetIsArray = Array.isArray(target);
  const sourceIsArray = Array.isArray(source);

  const targetIsNonArrayObject =
    !!target && 'object' === typeof target && !targetIsArray;
  const sourceIsNonArrayObject =
    !!source && 'object' === typeof source && !sourceIsArray;

  if (targetIsArray && sourceIsArray) {
    source
      .forEach((_/*sourceItem*/, idx) =>
        assignValue(target, source, idx)
      );
  } else if (targetIsNonArrayObject && sourceIsNonArrayObject) {
    Object
      .keys(source)
      .forEach(key =>
        assignValue(target, source, key)
      );
  } else {
    target = cloneDataStructure(source);
  }
  return target;

  function assignValue(target, source, key) {
    const sourceValue = source[key];

    if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

      target[key] = cloneDataStructure(sourceValue);
    } else {
      const targetValue = target[key];

      const targetValueIsObject =
        (!!targetValue && 'object' === typeof targetValue);
      const sourceValueIsObject =
        (!!sourceValue && 'object' === typeof sourceValue);
      const targetValueIsArray =
        targetValueIsObject && Array.isArray(targetValue);
      const sourceValueIsArray =
        sourceValueIsObject && Array.isArray(sourceValue);

      if (
        (targetValueIsArray && sourceValueIsArray) ||
        (targetValueIsObject && sourceValueIsObject)
      ) {
        mergeDataStructures(targetValue, sourceValue);
      } else {
        target[key] = cloneDataStructure(sourceValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
const cloneDataStructure =
  ('function' === typeof structuredClone)
  && structuredClone
  || (value => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
</script>
```

***Edit***

In case the OP wants to go for full inheritance with parameter passing/forwarding via `super` calls, the approach needs to be changed from defining each type's default `param` as own property.

This is due to `this` (hence `this.param`) is not allowed to be accessed before or during a `super` call. Thus each type's default `param` configuration has to be stored as e.g. local variable within each type's (or all type's) module scope. I would not declare such configurations as static class properties for they are exposed then, whereas a module scope ensures the protection of each default `param` config.

The before provided above example code which actually does not need any inheritance would change then to a real inheritance approach where the implementation might be similar to the next provided code ...

```js
const subRule2Param = {
  subparam: {
    values: [1, 2],
    value: 1,
  },
};
const subRule1Param = {
  subparam: {
    values: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    value: 'A',
  },
};
const baseRuleParam = { subparam: { value: 'base' } };

class Rule {
  param = {};

  constructor (options = {}) {
    // - a simple `Object.assign` is suitable due
    //   to `this.param` being an empty object.
    Object.assign(
      this.param,
      mergeDataStructures(
        cloneDataStructure(baseRuleParam),
        options
      )
    );
  }
}

class SubRule1 extends Rule {
  constructor (options = {}) {
    super(
      mergeDataStructures(
        cloneDataStructure(subRule1Param),
        options
      )
    );
  }
}
class SubRule2 extends Rule {
  constructor (options = {}) {
    super(
      mergeDataStructures(
        cloneDataStructure(subRule2Param),
        options
      )
    );
  }
}
const myRule1 = new SubRule1({ subparam: { value: 'B' } });
const myRule2 = new SubRule2({ subparam: { value: 2 } });

console.log({
  myRule1, // { subparam: { values: ['A', 'B', 'C'], value: 'B' }}
  myRule2, // { subparam: { values: [1, 2], value: 2 }}
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// - a pushing/patching approach of assigning/overwriting
//   target-values of deeply nested data-structures.
function mergeDataStructures(target, source) {

  const targetIsArray = Array.isArray(target);
  const sourceIsArray = Array.isArray(source);

  const targetIsNonArrayObject =
    !!target && 'object' === typeof target && !targetIsArray;
  const sourceIsNonArrayObject =
    !!source && 'object' === typeof source && !sourceIsArray;

  if (targetIsArray && sourceIsArray) {
    source
      .forEach((_/*sourceItem*/, idx) =>
        assignValue(target, source, idx)
      );
  } else if (targetIsNonArrayObject && sourceIsNonArrayObject) {
    Object
      .keys(source)
      .forEach(key =>
        assignValue(target, source, key)
      );
  } else {
    target = cloneDataStructure(source);
  }
  return target;

  function assignValue(target, source, key) {
    const sourceValue = source[key];

    if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

      target[key] = cloneDataStructure(sourceValue);
    } else {
      const targetValue = target[key];

      const targetValueIsObject =
        (!!targetValue && 'object' === typeof targetValue);
      const sourceValueIsObject =
        (!!sourceValue && 'object' === typeof sourceValue);
      const targetValueIsArray =
        targetValueIsObject && Array.isArray(targetValue);
      const sourceValueIsArray =
        sourceValueIsObject && Array.isArray(sourceValue);

      if (
        (targetValueIsArray && sourceValueIsArray) ||
        (targetValueIsObject && sourceValueIsObject)
      ) {
        mergeDataStructures(targetValue, sourceValue);
      } else {
        target[key] = cloneDataStructure(sourceValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
const cloneDataStructure =
  ('function' === typeof structuredClone)
  && structuredClone
  || (value => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
</script>
```

***Edit** due to a user's comment ...*

> *"Your mergeDataStructures implementation is needlessly complex for the specific usecase of the OP. Just do the simplest possible thing."* – Adam

> > *"*"... is needlessly complex for the specific usecase of the OP"_ ... how does one know? The two provided solutions (with and whithout parameter passing to `super`) together with each of its explanation are answering the OP's question about the OP's class design/concept. And the custom merge implementation got provided in addition for it will cover merging complex nested data structures better than e.g. underscore/lodash merge."_ – Peter Seliger

One also could make use of the `_.merge` and `_.cloneDeep` methods of either libraries [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) or [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/).

```js
const subRule2Param = {
  subparam: {
    values: [1, 2],
    value: 1,
  },
};
const subRule1Param = {
  subparam: {
    values: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    value: 'A',
  },
};
const baseRuleParam = { subparam: { value: 'base' } };

class Rule {
  param = {};

  constructor (options = {}) {
    // - a simple `Object.assign` is suitable due
    //   to `this.param` being an empty object.
    Object.assign(
      this.param,
      _.merge(
        _.cloneDeep(baseRuleParam),
        options
      )
    );
  }
}

class SubRule1 extends Rule {
  constructor (options = {}) {
    super(
      _.merge(
        _.cloneDeep(subRule1Param),
        options
      )
    );
  }
}
class SubRule2 extends Rule {
  constructor (options = {}) {
    super(
      _.merge(
        _.cloneDeep(subRule2Param),
        options
      )
    );
  }
}
const myRule1 = new SubRule1({ subparam: { value: 'B' } });
const myRule2 = new SubRule2({ subparam: { value: 2 } });

console.log({
  myRule1, // { subparam: { values: ['A', 'B', 'C'], value: 'B' }}
  myRule2, // { subparam: { values: [1, 2], value: 2 }}
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your mergeDataStructures implementation is needlessly complex for the specific usecase of the OP. Just do the simplest possible thing.

Comment: _"... is needlessly complex for the specific usecase of the OP"_ ... how does one know? The two provided solutions (with and whithout parameter passing to `super`) together with each of its explanation are answering the OP's question about the OP's class design/concept. And the custom merge implementation got provided in addition for it will cover merging complex nested data structures better than e.g. underscore/lodash merge.

Answer (score -1):

The pattern you're looking for is

```
actual_params = Object.assign({}, defaults, user_options)
```

To make this work with inheritance, `defaults` must be static:

```js
class Whatever {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.config = Object.assign({}, this.constructor.defaults, options)
    }
}

class Deriv extends Whatever {
    static defaults = {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'pam'}
}

let a = new Deriv()
console.log(a.config)

let b = new Deriv({'spam': 'hello'})
console.log(b.config)
```

If you want to merge them *deeply*, this is another, more complicated story.

Answer (score -2):

To access the param parameter from parent class constructor, you should not use `this.param`, instead just use `console.log(param)` which is passed as parameter to the contructor of parent class. `this.param` is a pointer to the variable of that class only.

```js
    class Rule {
      param = {}
      constructor (param) {
        console.log(param)
      }
    }

    class SubRule extends Rule {
      param = {
        subparam1: 'test'
      }
      constructor (param) {
        super(param)
      }
    }
    
    let myrule = new SubRule()

    // Object {  } instead of Object { subparam1: 'test' }
```

Something like this may work for you.